# Problem with the cache on Angular's application web

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I am working on angular js application.

For the first time application is working fine, when we release a new build with new changes, when the user trying to access the page browser is still loading the old files new changes are showing in the browser, to load the new changes user has to clear the cache and reload the application.

Sometimes with browser cache cleanup it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-and-js-files

Answer (score 0):

Try these meta tags:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
</head>
```